# Multilanguage String with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a class `LocalizedString` which can store the same string in multiple languages. Now I want to use this class in an EF Core model. But I would like to tell the EF that it should map all values to columns in the same table, instead of an own table. So for each `LocalizedString` property in `MyEntity` I want to have a column for each language in the table of `MyEntity`. So the property `Name` should create the columns `Name_en`, `Name_fr`, `Name_de` and so on. The list of possible languages will not change on runtime but on compile time.

When `MyEntity` is loaded from database, the columns should be mapped backed to a `LocalizedString`.

Is this even possible with EF Core? Can anyone point my to the right direction how to implement this?

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public LocalizedString Name { get; set; }
}

public class LocalizedString
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> Values;

    public LocalizedString()
    {
        Values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public void Set(string isoCode, string value = "")
    {
        Values.Add(isoCode, value);
    }

    public string Get(string isoCode, string defaultValue = "")
    {
        Values.TryGetValue(isoCode, out defaultValue);
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should work out-of-the-box when you use the ComplexTypeAttribute on your LocalizedString class and have properties called en, fr, de, and so on, instead of a Dictionary. because with the ComplexTypeAttribute EF will auto-map each property of such class to its own column and if you use `LocalizedString Xyz` each column will be prefixed with Xyz.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Owned properties should work but sadly I have the limitation, that the available languages are defined outside my project. So project A uses my library B in which the ```LocalizedString``` and some models are defined. So I need a way, that Project A can defined the available languages but still use my ```LocalizedString``` and models. Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Hi, have you done some progress? I want to use your approach (I have done previously in other ORMs as Laravel-Eloquent and Sprint-Hibernate) for my persistent multilanguage.